# I have a chat application with PHP and Ajax. I want to display users according to sent or received messages using php query

Tags: php

Here is my code that outputs users

In the messages table I have **msg_id int, incoming_msg_id varchar, outgoing_msg_id varchar, msg varchar, msg_time varchar.**

```
$outgoing = $_SESSION['unique_id'];

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT unique_id = outgoing ");
```

I just want to display users according to message. Just like messenger when u receive or send messages it shows at the top..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, you need to have a way of identifying which user is sending a message, and who's receiving. I think your `incoming_msg_id` and `outgoing_msg_id` are what you use to fulfil that purpose right? Well you should probably give them more descriptive names like `receiver_id` and `sender_id`.
Then for each user, you can display the most recent messages at the top by using this query:

```sql
SELECT * from `messages` where `receiver_id` = <current_user_id>
ORDER BY `msg_time` DESC
```

For this query to work properly, you also need to change the datatype of the `msg_time` from `varchar` to `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Still not working

Comment: I got no output the users list became empty